# Undefined attribute inside an event handler

Tags: reactjs

For some reason, I´m not being able to access my current target´s attribute inside my event handler. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong, as the this shouldn´t be a problem.

Element:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon travelModeOption="DRIVING" onClick ={this. calculateAndDisplayRoute}size={"lg"} icon={faCar}/>
```

Event handler

```
calculateAndDisplayRoute = (e)=> {
    let travelModeOption;
    {travelModeOption ? e.currentTarget.getAttribute("travelModeOption") : null};
    let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(this.newMap);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));
    console.log(this.state.start);
    console.log(travelModeOption)
    let start=this.state.start;
    let end = this.state.currentMarker[0].getPosition();
    console.log(end);
    directionsService.route({
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: travelModeOption || 'DRIVING'
    }, (response, status) =>{
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        this.setState({distance: response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value});
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On click you are calling a different handler `onClick={this.calculateRoute}` instead of `calculateAndDisplayRoute`.

change it to

```
onClick={this.calculateAndDisplayRoute}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing, but my guess is, the callback is not bound to the original component, so it has no `this`. Try this:

```
onClick={this.calculateAndDisplayRoute.bind(this)}
```

This will register a callback that is bound the original component. In other words, it will set `this` in the callback function to be available when it's actually triggered.

Comment: but the event handler is posted in the question, why do you assume this? and what if he's using arrow functions, like function posted in the question.

Comment: Like I said, the question is a bit confusing. This was just a hunch, based on the error message from the question title. Since this error is quite common.

Comment: About the arrow function, it's not clear if that's a class attribute or just a function defined out of scope. Again...the question is confusing. rs

Comment: Ok, I get you now.